# Change viewForHeaderInSection if that header is on top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have `UITableView` with two sections. Now, because I wanted additional space for header between 0 and 1st section, I've gave them different heights:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 30;
            break;
        case 1:
            return 60;
        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

Now, this is working pretty good, I have space view and then in last 30px of view I have label. Problem is when that view is scrolled on top, there is 30px spacing between navigationBar and label(that space view that I made).
Is there any way to detect is header of section 1 is scrolled to top and change height for it if it's on top?

Comment: You can implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method and check when the frame of the header is at the top of the table.  Figuring out the frame of the header and adjusting it appropriately is left as an exercise for the reader.  Why is why this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I reviewed what I could do, I've removed this space view and added `height for footer` in section 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your tableview to group style

```
tableView.style = UITableViewStyle.Grouped
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but could you be more specific please?

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: ZHZ, this solved part of problem, but now headers are not staying on top of view. Thank you for answer, I will consider this as answer if I couldn't find another solution.